# IndexOutOfBoundsException while gradle sync with realm-java

Tags: java, android, realm

i install realm in my android application, just change my bbdd model and extends from realmobject and change lists by realmlist and i get this error while gradle sync:

```
 with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Exception stack-trace is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':storage:compileReleaseJava'. 
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
 at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
 at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
 at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
 at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
 at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
 at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
 at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
 at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
 at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
 at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
 at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
 at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
 at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
 at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
 at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
 at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
 at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
 at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
 at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:42)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:97)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:50)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:36)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:34)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
 at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:158)
 at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:138)
 at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:92)
 at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
 ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at com.sun.tools.javac.util.List.get(List.java:421)
 at io.realm.processor.RealmProxyClassGenerator.generate(RealmProxyClassGenerator.java:172)
 at io.realm.processor.RealmProcessor.process(RealmProcessor.java:73)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
 ... 65 more
```

Here its my model.

```
public class WorkDB extends RealmObject {
    private String team;
    private String clientId;
    private String workString;
    private String signerName;
    private String signPath;
    private RealmList photoList;
    private Date date;
    private String id;
    private boolean downloaded;
    private String address;
    private String postalCode;
    private String town;
    private String province;
    private String phone;
    private RealmList<ReportDB> reports;

    public WorkDB(String team, String clientId, String workString, Date date, String id, boolean downloaded,
                  String address, String postalCode, String town, String province, String phone, RealmList<ReportDB> reports) {

        super();
        this.team = team;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.workString = workString;
        this.photoList = new RealmList<>();
        this.date = date;
        this.id = id;
        this.downloaded = downloaded;
        this.address = address;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.town = town;
        this.province = province;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.reports = reports;
    }

    public WorkDB() {
        this.photoList = new RealmList();
    }

    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(String team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getWorkString() {
        return workString;
    }

    public void setWorkString(String workString) {
        this.workString = workString;
    }

    public String getSignerName() {
        return signerName;
    }

    public void setSignerName(String signerName) {
        this.signerName = signerName;
    }

    public String getSignPath() {
        return signPath;
    }

    public void setSignPath(String signPath) {
        this.signPath = signPath;
    }

    public RealmList getPhotoList() {
        return photoList;
    }

    public void setPhotoList(RealmList photoList) {
        this.photoList = photoList;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isDownloaded() {
        return downloaded;
    }

    public void setDownloaded(boolean downloaded) {
        this.downloaded = downloaded;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public RealmList<ReportDB> getReports() {
        return reports;
    }

    public void setReports(RealmList<ReportDB> reports) {
        this.reports = reports;
    }

}

public class ReportDB extends RealmObject {
    private int idReport;
    private String nameReport;
    private RealmList<ReplieGroupDB> repliesGroup;
    private RealmList<QuestionGroupDB> questionGroups;

    public ReportDB(int idReport, String nameReport, RealmList<ReplieGroupDB> repliesGroup, RealmList<QuestionGroupDB> questionGroups) {
        this.idReport = idReport;
        this.nameReport = nameReport;
        this.repliesGroup = repliesGroup;
        this.questionGroups = questionGroups;
    }

    public ReportDB() {

    }

    public List<QuestionGroupDB> getQuestionGroups() {
        return questionGroups;
    }

    public void setQuestionGroups(RealmList<QuestionGroupDB> questionGroups) {
        this.questionGroups = questionGroups;
    }

    public int getIdReport() {
        return idReport;
    }

    public void setIdReport(int idReport) {
        this.idReport = idReport;
    }

    public String getNameReport() {
        return nameReport;
    }

    public void setNameReport(String nameReport) {
        this.nameReport = nameReport;
    }

    public List<ReplieGroupDB> getRepliesGroup() {
        return repliesGroup;
    }

    public void setRepliesGroup(RealmList<ReplieGroupDB> repliesGroup) {
        this.repliesGroup = repliesGroup;
    }
}

public class ReplieGroupDB extends RealmObject {
    private int idReplieGroup;
    private String name;
    private RealmList<ReplieDB> replies;
    private QuestionGroupDB questionGroups;

    public ReplieGroupDB(int idReplieGroup, RealmList<ReplieDB> replies, String name, QuestionGroupDB questionGroups) {
        super();
        this.idReplieGroup = idReplieGroup;
        this.replies = replies;
        this.name = name;
        this.questionGroups = questionGroups;
    }

    public ReplieGroupDB() {

    }


    public int getIdReplieGroup() {
        return idReplieGroup;
    }

    public void setIdReplieGroup(int idReplieGroup) {
        this.idReplieGroup = idReplieGroup;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public RealmList<ReplieDB> getReplies() {
        return replies;
    }

    public void setReplies(RealmList<ReplieDB> replies) {
        this.replies = replies;
    }

    public QuestionGroupDB getQuestionGroups() {
        return questionGroups;
    }

    public void setQuestionGroups(QuestionGroupDB questionGroups) {
        this.questionGroups = questionGroups;
    }


}
ated by usuario on 14/7/14.
 */
public class ReplieTypeDB extends RealmObject {
    private int idReplieType;
    private String name;

    public ReplieTypeDB(int idReplieType, String name) {
        super();
        this.idReplieType = idReplieType;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ReplieTypeDB() {
        super();
    }


    public int getIdReplieType() {
        return idReplieType;
    }

    public void setIdReplieType(int idReplieType) {
        this.idReplieType = idReplieType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
public class ReplieDB extends RealmObject {
    private QuestionDB question;
    private String reply;
    private int replieId;

    public ReplieDB() {
        super();
    }

    public ReplieDB(QuestionDB question, String reply, int replieId) {

        this.question = question;
        if (reply != null)
            this.reply = reply;
        else
            this.reply = "";
        this.replieId = replieId;
    }

    public QuestionDB getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(QuestionDB question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getReply() {
        return reply;
    }

    public void setReply(String reply) {
        this.reply = reply;
    }

    public int getReplieId() {
        return replieId;
    }

    public void setReplieId(int replieId) {
        this.replieId = replieId;
    }
}


public class QuestionsInReplieDB extends RealmObject {

    private int idQuestionGroup;
    private String nameReport;
    private RealmList<QuestionDB> questionDBs;
    private int times;

    public QuestionsInReplieDB(int idQuestionGroup, String nameReport, RealmList<QuestionDB> questionDBs, int times) {
        super();
        this.idQuestionGroup = idQuestionGroup;
        this.nameReport = nameReport;
        this.questionDBs = questionDBs;
        this.times = times;
    }

    public QuestionsInReplieDB() {
        super();
    }

    public int getIdQuestionGroup() {
        return idQuestionGroup;
    }

    public void setIdQuestionGroup(int idQuestionGroup) {
        this.idQuestionGroup = idQuestionGroup;
    }

    public String getNameReport() {
        return nameReport;
    }

    public void setNameReport(String nameReport) {
        this.nameReport = nameReport;
    }

    public List<QuestionDB> getQuestionDBs() {
        return questionDBs;
    }

    public void setQuestionDBs(RealmList<QuestionDB> questionDBs) {
        this.questionDBs = questionDBs;
    }

    public int getTimes() {
        return times;
    }

    public void setTimes(int times) {
        this.times = times;
    }
}

public class QuestionGroupDB extends RealmObject {

    private int idQuestionGroupInReplie;
    private String nameQuestionGroupInReplie;
    private RealmList<QuestionDB> questions;
    private int times;

    public QuestionGroupDB() {
    }

    public int getIdQuestionGroupInReplie() {
        return idQuestionGroupInReplie;
    }

    public void setIdQuestionGroupInReplie(int idQuestionGroupInReplie) {
        this.idQuestionGroupInReplie = idQuestionGroupInReplie;
    }

    public String getNameQuestionGroupInReplie() {
        return nameQuestionGroupInReplie;
    }

    public void setNameQuestionGroupInReplie(String nameQuestionGroupInReplie) {
        this.nameQuestionGroupInReplie = nameQuestionGroupInReplie;
    }

    public List<QuestionDB> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(RealmList<QuestionDB> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public int getTimes() {
        return times;
    }

    public void setTimes(int times) {
        this.times = times;
    }
}


public class QuestionDB extends RealmObject{
    public QuestionDB() {
    }

    private int idQuestion;
    private String question;
    private int order;
    private ReplieTypeDB replieType;

    public int getIdQuestion() {
        return idQuestion;
    }

    public void setIdQuestion(int idQuestion) {
        this.idQuestion = idQuestion;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public ReplieTypeDB getReplieType() {
        return replieType;
    }

    public void setReplieType(ReplieTypeDB replieType) {
        this.replieType = replieType;
    }
}
```

RealmList could be infered with type, i didn't it in photoList.

Comment: Can you post your model class that extends RealmObject as well?

Comment: I will edit mi first question.

Comment: Solved https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1121